# Passing Html tag in Update query

Tags: html, sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

There is an existing table in database where I want to update one column. If I right click on the table--->select edit 200 rows and try to edit the cell data it says that the cell is read-only. I am using SQL management studio 2008R2. 
So I was trying to update it using an update Query but I am pretty new to the SQL queries and the whole database thing. Is this the proper way to pass an HTML tag in queries?

```
UPDATE OutputTemplate
  SET emailText='(<p>Thank you for your  gift of {Amount} to the {CommunityName}</p><br />Support & Charity Campaign.<br />
 --------------------------------------------
 ---          Transaction Detail          ---
 --------------------------------------------
 <span>Credit Card Details</span> 
 <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Personal Info Details & Amount</span>)'
 WHERE id='2'
```

It's showing some parsing error, incorrect syntax while executing the query.

Sorry to ask such a basic question but I tried to google it, unfortunatelly nothing showed up useful.

Thanks

Comment: Is it intentional that the () are INSIDE the string?

Comment: @sircapsalot Nope First I tried without () that dint work so I just tried with ()...even that didn't workout

Comment: seems all working fine here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a27ef/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the newlines from the query.

`UPDATE OutputTemplate
  SET emailText="<p>Thank you for your  gift of {Amount} to the {CommunityName}</p><br />Support & Charity Campaign.<br />--------------------------------------------<br />---          Transaction Detail          ---<br />--------------------------------------------<br /><span>Credit Card Details</span><br /><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Personal Info Details & Amount</span>"
 WHERE id='2'`

Comment: Error near identifier text. Expecting OUTPUT. .... I got this error msg...it said error while parsing the content

Comment: Fix the query to fit on one line.

Comment: In the Personal Info Details & Amount <span> I have content with ' . Therefore the query is ending at that ' spot so its not parsing anything after that and giving error for the remaining content. How to deal with " & ' if its part of your content.

Comment: for heavens sake... `UPDATE OutputTemplate SET emailText="<p>Thank you for your gift of {Amount} to the {CommunityName}</p><br />Support & Charity Campaign.<br />--------------------------------------------<br />--- Transaction Detail ---<br />--------------------------------------------<br /><span>Credit Card Details</span><br /><span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">Personal Info Details & Amount</span>" WHERE id='2'`  haha

Comment: I guess it was very basic...sorry for the silly question  & thanks a lot for your time and patience.. It worked :)

Comment: How to do for a whole html file where we have both the ' and " :(